# Fast std::vector<bool> Reset

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I have a *very* large vector of bits (10s of millions of "presence" bits) whose size known only at run-time (i.e. no `std::bitset`), but known before actual usage, so the container can be pre-allocated.

This vector is initially all zeros with single bits set incrementally, sparsely and randomly.  My only use of this container is direct random access - checking "presence" (no STL).
After trying several alternative containers it seems that `std::vector<bool>` is a good fit for my needs (despite its conceptual problems).

Every once in a while I need to reset *all* the bits in this vector.
Since it is so big, I cannot afford a full reset of *all* its elements. However, I know the indices of all the set bits so I can reset them individually.

Since `std::vector<bool>` represents `bool`s as bits, each such reset involves extra shifts and other such adjustment operations.

Is there a (portable) way to do a "rough", low-accuracy, reset?
One that will reset the *whole* integer that my requested bit belongs to, avoiding any extra additional operations ?

Comment: How sparse is your vector? Would using a `std::set` of indices or pointers to the present elements be an option?

Comment: @anderas: No, not really. I need super-fast O(1) lookup.

Comment: "However, I know the indices of all the set bits"... Hmmm... In that case why do you need that huge array at all ?

Comment: Wrapping a vector of ints in a class of your own (access via bitshift for vector index and old fashioned bit-wise AND) cannot be much slower than what a vector<bool> does (because it must do something along these lines, too). That would allow you to trivially set the desired ints directly.

Comment: @borisbn: Let me guess -- a map with O(log n) is already too slow.

Comment: You still haven't answered anderas's question - *how spare is your vector*?  If you've pretty consistently got less than a few bits per memory page, the cache might be the performance bottleneck anyway.  If you've got around >= 1 bit per couple hundred indices, `clear` is probably about as good as you'd get anyway....

Comment: What is wrong with std::vector<bool>::assign (which likely has a  similar performance as memset)?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: I assume he doesn't want to perform a memset of 100MB but just assign 100 ints or so. Apparently he has done some testing too, so the performance anxiety is perhaps not completely unjustified.

Comment: @borisbn: Each is used in different places with different usage profiles.

Comment: @PeterSchneider: I did roll my own class, as you suggest, but was considering using `std::vector<bool>` hence my question :-).

Comment: @TonyD: I may have around 5% set bits.

Comment: Hmm... 5% (1/20) means that most integers (or bitsets in Danvil's solution) will have one of their bits set, doesn't it? In that case I can imagine that clearing the whole vector, and if in doubt just memsetting it, wouldn't be bad performance-wise.

Comment: @AdiShavit: 5% is more than 1 per 32-bit word (and `clear` might be written for 64-at-a-time clearing), and you've said they're effectively randomly, so you can't possibly improve on `clear()` if you're having to consult some other list then conditionally clear certain words.

Comment: @TonyD: I guess I'm just around the 1/32 = 3.1% boundary. From my measurements my indexed (single-bit) reset is about twice as fast as a full `clear()`.

Comment: @AdiShavit: that just doesn't make sense, so I wonder if you're benchmarking an optimised build, what timing routines you used, whether you properly used runtime inputs and outputs to avoid compile-time elimination of parts of the processing you do want to measure etc., whether the Standard Library implementation you're using is poor.  Do please post full code somewhere, and details of your system, compiler and command-line options, and we can find out exactly why....

Comment: @TonyD: You got me thinking, and I presume it's because my set bits aren't necessarily uniformly distributed. They might actually tend to cluster which should explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Oh fair enough... be interesting to hear your timing results with Danvil's code then.

Comment: @TonyD: I ended up using my own `size_t` based container (which was jsu slightly faster than an `std::bitset` version like @Danvil proposed). Using "rough" reset is about twice as fast as the direct bit reset. It is also about 15% of the full vector reset. From more tests it seems that my bits are on average sparser than I had indicated above, getting down to below 0.1%.

Comment: @AdiShavit: thanks for filling us in... good that your solution's working well.  Cheers.

Comment: @AdiShavit: edited my answer with some code I'm hoping you might want to try out... hoping it'll prove massively faster. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 "Dense"**:

If you need a "dense" container I would suggest you use a mixture of `vector` and `bitset`.

We store bits as a sequence of bitsets, thus we can use `bitset::reset` on each "chunk" to reset them all. `DynamicBitset::resize` can be used to make room for the correct number of bits.

```
class DynamicBitset
{
private:
    static const unsigned BITS_LEN = 64; // or 32, or more?
    typedef std::bitset<BITS_LEN> Bits;
    std::vector<Bits> data_;
public:
    DynamicBitset(size_t len=0) {
        resize(len);
    }
    // reset all bits to false
    void reset() {
        for(auto it=data_.begin(); it!=data_.end(); ++it) {
            it->reset(); // we can use the fast bitfield::reset :)
        }
    }
    // reset the whole bitset belonging to bit i
    void reset_approx(size_t i) {
        data_[i/BITS_LEN].reset();
    }
    // make room for len bits
    void resize(size_t len) {
        data_.resize(len/BITS_LEN + 1);
    }
    // access a bit
    Bits::reference operator[](size_t i) {
        size_t k = i/BITS_LEN;
        return data_[k][i-k*BITS_LEN];
    }
    bool operator[](size_t i) const {
        size_t k = i/BITS_LEN;
        return data_[k][i-k*BITS_LEN];
    }
};
```

**Method 2 "Sparse"**:

If you store only very few bits, you can also go with a mixture of `map` and `bitset`.

Here we store chunks only if there is at least on bit set in it. This has additional costs for accessing bits as we need a lookup into a `std::map` which has `O(log N)`, but uses much less memory.

Additionally the function reset does exactly what you stated in your question - it only touches areas where you have set a bit.

`SparseDynamicBitset` is a good choice when you have very long sequences of bits which are always false, e.g. for 1000...000100...010, and not for 0101000111010110.

```
class SparseDynamicBitset
{
private:
    static const unsigned BITS_LEN = 64; // ?
    typedef std::bitset<BITS_LEN> Bits;
    std::map<unsigned,Bits> data_;
public:
    // reset all "stored" bits to false
    void reset() {
        for(auto it=data_.begin(); it!=data_.end(); ++it) {
            it->second.reset(); // uses bitfield::reset :)
        }
    }
    // access a bit
    Bits::reference operator[](size_t i) {
        size_t k = i/BITS_LEN;
        return data_[k][i-k*BITS_LEN];
    }
    bool operator[](size_t i) const {
        size_t k = i/BITS_LEN;
        auto it = data_.find(k);
        if(it == it.end()) {
            return false; // the default
        }
        return it->second[i-k*BITS_LEN];
    }
};
```

Comment: I think your classes are missing the OP's requirement to quickly delete a given integer (or whatever contains the bits) without the costly bit access. And if a map was fast enough he'd use one to begin with.

Comment: Why? "Every once in a while I need to reset all the bits in this vector." - my function resets are very fast ways to do this.

Comment: "Since it is so big, I cannot afford a full reset of all its elements.". I assume he cannot afford to dynamically let the vector grow, either, because that would involve a copy of _all_ of its elements, which is as costly as zeroing them.

Comment: And why is this a problem with my implementation?

Comment: `for(auto it=data_.begin(); it!=data_.end(); ++it)  it->reset();` is probably 10^6 or 10^7 operations, as opposed to the 10^2 or 10^3 which the OP seems to envision. Or am I misunderstanding? But this conversation is a little difficult because you change your implementation every time I say something ;-). And then you resize() your vector on demand which is probably unacceptable to the OP performancewise.

Comment: Sorry ;) I added a function `reset_approx` which should do exactly what he wants.

Comment: The "dense" solution now answers the question as asked, the "sparse" solution adds an alternative approach.

Comment: Almost. I assume we need a ctor with a size_t arg because the internal vector should be created with the desired capacity right away. There is no time to copy many MB around during its use. (If I interpret the OP correctly in that while the size is only known at runtime, it stays constant after that, and performance is of utmost concern). Then you have earned the +1 for our common effort ;-) (Well, one could just call resize() after creation, but that smells .)

Comment: I changed that already. There is a function `resize` and `operator[]` does not call `vector::resize` anymore (that was kind of stupid).

Comment: Why use `std::bitset` and not `size_t`s directly? What is to be gained by `std::bitset` extra non-`size_t` support?

Comment: @AdiShavit: You do not have to re-implement some of the `bitset` operations, e.g. `operator[]`. Additionally you can decide to use larger chunks with the sparse container, e.g. 256 bits per chunk. In the end using `std::bitset` is just more convenient at no additional costs.

Comment: You can't just cast a reference to a bit within a `bitset` to `bool&`: [bitset::reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference) is a proxy object with casting operator, so your code returns a reference to a temporary.

Comment: @TonyD: Thanks for the hint. Fixed it.

Comment: @Danvil: I guess it depends on the actual implementation, but since `std::bitset` needs to support non-`size_t` bit-counts it *does* in fact have some additional bit-manipulation costs, but I understand your reasoning. I had assumed that was it, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything else.

Comment: @AdiShavit: "since std::bitset needs to support non-size_t bit-counts it does in fact have some additional bit-manipulation costs" - that's a quality of implementation and optimiser issue, and not necessarily true.

Comment: @Danvil: nearly there... `Bits::reference&` is still a reference to a temporary... best to return the proxy by value.

Comment: @AdiShavit: When you use a good value for `BITS_LEN` (i.e. a multiple of `sizeof(unsigned long)`) you probably do not have that issue. But if speed is the main issue, I would just benchmark it!

Comment: I am accepting this answer for its completeness. I did end up using my own `size_t` based container which was marginally faster than your suggested dense `std::bitset` based version.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a (portable) way to do a "rough", low-accuracy, reset?
>   One that will reset the whole integer that my requested bit belongs to, avoiding any extra additional operations?

No, and no.  (Not for that container type)

FWIW, I wrote a data type that may help you with large sparse bit sets (you'll need to wrap it in an outer type that creates an array of them etc.).  The type is 32 bits wide and tracks the on/off status of 1024 bits by using the 32 bits to either (worst case = > 3 bits set) store a pointer to a `vector<unsigned>`, or (typically) using the 32-bits as a 2-bit size/count and up to 3 embedded 10-bit indices of set bits.  When the `vector`'s not needed, this achieves a 32x storage density improvement over a `std::bitset<>`, which should help reduce memory cache misses.

NOTES: It's crucial that the size member - `in_use` - be aligned over the least significant bits in the `vector*`, such that any legitimate pointer (which will have at least 4-byte alignment) will necessarily have an `in_use` value of 0.  Written for 32-bit apps where `uintptr_t == 32`, but the same concept can be used to create a 64-bit version; the data type needs to use `uintptr_t` so it can store a pointer-to-`vector` when needed, so must match the 32- or 64-bit execution mode.

Code includes tests showing random operations affect `bitset`s and `Bit_Packer_32`s identically.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

class Bit_Packer_32
{
    // Invariants:
    // - 0 bits set: u_ == p_ == a == b == c == 0
    // - 1 bit set:  in_use == 1, a meaningful, b == c == 0
    // - 2 bits set: in_use == 2, a & b meaningful, c == 0
    // - 3 bits set: in_use == 3, a & b & c meaningful
    // - >3 bits:    in_use == 0, p_ != 0
    // NOTE: differentiating 0 from >3 depends on a == b == c == 0 for former

  public:
    Bit_Packer_32() : u_(0) { }

    class Reference
    {
      public:
        Reference(Bit_Packer_32& p, size_t n) : p_(p), n_(n) { }

        Reference& operator=(bool b) { p_.set(n_, b); return *this; }
        operator bool() const { return p_[n_]; }

      private:
        Bit_Packer_32& p_;
        size_t n_;
    };

    Reference operator[](size_t n) { return Reference(*this, n); }

    void set(size_t n)
    {
        switch (in_use)
        {
          case 0:
            if (p_)
            {
               if (std::find(p_->begin(), p_->end(), n) == p_->end())
                   p_->push_back(n);
            }
            else
            { in_use = 1; a = n; }
            break;
          case 1: if (a != n) { in_use = 2; b = n; } break;
          case 2: if (a != n && b != n) { in_use = 3; c = n; } break;
          case 3: if (a == n || b == n || c == n) break;
                  V* p = new V(4);
                  (*p)[0] = a; (*p)[1] = b; (*p)[2] = c; (*p)[3] = n;
                  p_ = p;
        }
    }

    void reset(size_t n)
    {
        switch (in_use)
        {
          case 0:
            if (p_)
            {
                V::iterator i = std::find(p_->begin(), p_->end(), n);
                if (i != p_->end())
                {
                    p_->erase(i);
                    if (p_->size() == 3)
                    {
                        // faster to copy out w/o erase, but tedious
                        int p0 = (*p_)[0], p1 = (*p_)[1], p2 = (*p_)[2];
                        delete p_;
                        a = p0; b = p1; c = p2;
                        in_use = 3;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;

          case 1: if (a == n) { u_ = 0; /* in_use = a = 0 */ } break;
          case 2: if (a == n) { in_use = 1; a = b; b = 0; break; }
                  else if (b == n) { in_use = 1; b = 0; break; }
          case 3:      if (a == n) a = c;
                  else if (b == n) b = c;
                  else if (c == n) ;
                  else break;
                  in_use = 2;
                  c = 0;
        }
    }

    void reset_all()
    {
        if (in_use == 0) delete p_;
        u_ = 0;
    }

    size_t count() const { return in_use ? in_use : p_ ? p_->size() : 0; }

    void set(size_t n, bool b) { if (b) set(n); else reset(n); }

    bool operator[](size_t n) const
    {
        switch (in_use)
        {
          case 0:
            return p_ && std::find(p_->begin(), p_->end(), n) != p_->end();
          case 1: return n == a;
          case 2: return n == a || n == b;
          case 3: return n == a || n == b || n == c;
        }
    }

    // e.g. operate_on<std::bitset<1024>, Op_Set>()
    //      operate_on<std::set<unsigned>, Op_Insert>()
    //      operate_on<std::vector<unsigned>, Op_Push_Back>()
    template <typename T, typename Op>
    T operate_on(const Op& op = Op()) const
    {
        T result;
        switch (in_use)
        {
          case 0:
            if (p_)
                for (V::const_iterator i = p_->begin(); i != p_->end(); ++i)
                     op(result, *i);
            break;
          case 3: op(result, c);
          case 2: op(result, b);
          case 1: op(result, a);
        }
        return result;
    }

  private:
    union
    {
        uintptr_t u_;
        typedef std::vector<unsigned> V;
        V* p_;
        struct
        {
            unsigned in_use : 2;
            unsigned a : 10;
            unsigned b : 10;
            unsigned c : 10;
        };
    };
};

struct Op_Insert
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void operator()(T& t, const U& u) const { t.insert(u); }
};

struct Op_Set
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void operator()(T& t, const U& u) const { t.set(u); }
};

struct Op_Push_Back
{
    template <typename T, typename U>
    void operator()(T& t, const U& u) const { t.push_back(u); }
};

#define TEST(A, B, MSG) \
    do { \
        bool pass = (A) == (B); \
        if (pass) break; \
        std::cout << "@" << __LINE__ << ": (" #A " == " #B ") "; \
        std::cout << (pass ? "pass\n" : "FAIL\n"); \
        std::cout << "  (" << (A) << " ==\n"; \
        std::cout << "   " << (B) << ")\n"; \
        std::cout << MSG << std::endl; \
    } while (false)

template <size_t N>
std::set<unsigned> to_set(const std::bitset<N>& bs)
{
    std::set<unsigned> result;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        if (bs[i]) result.insert(i);
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<T>& s)
{
    for (std::set<T>::const_iterator i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (i != s.begin()) os << ' ';
        os << *i;
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    TEST(sizeof(uintptr_t), 4, "designed for 32-bit uintptr_t");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        Bit_Packer_32 bp;
        std::bitset<1024> bs;
        for (int j = 0; j < 1 + i % 10; ++j)
        {
            int n = rand() % 1024;
            int v = rand() % 2;
            bs[n] = v;
            bp[n] = v;
            // TEST(bp.get_bitset(), bs);
            TEST((bp.operate_on<std::set<unsigned>, Op_Insert>()), to_set(bs),
                 "j " << j << ", n " << n << ", v " << v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a deeper look and see how it can be converted to work on x64 as well.

Comment: @AdiShavit: hint: change to `in_use : 4`, `a : 12`... add `d : 12` and `e :12`, then all the `switch (in_use)` need fairly obvious tweaks.  Going to be a little tedious, but pretty quick and easy.  5x 12-bit indices let each 64-bit packer track up to 4096 bits... with "below 0.1%" set that should be ok, but you could always decide to have the outer class track only 2048 bits per packer, giving fewer cases where they fall back on pointers to vectors.

Comment: @AdiShavit 64-bit version uploaded to https://ideone.com/5lnteC - won't run properly there because ideone only offers 32-bit compilation AFAIK, but don't want this answer crazy-long so just using it as code hosting....

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no portable way to do so, because there is no requirement to use bit fields, only a recommendation. If you want to be portable, you might want to implement your own, based for example on `std::vector<uint8_t>`  or a `std::bitset`.

Comment: I did exactly that, though `std::vector<size_t>` might be more efficient on some architectures.